# calling Label.Text (in C#) vs Label.innerHTML causing unexpected results

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I have some HTML

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive table-bordered">  
 <tr class="row">
  <td colspan="3" class="col-md-3">Location</td>
  <td colspan="4" class="col-md-4">Info</td>
  <td colspan="2" class="col-md-2">Date/Time</td>
  <td colspan="1" class="col-md-1">Mandatory</td>
  <td colspan="2" class="col-md-2">Edit</td>
 </tr>
 <asp:Label ID="lblNewProjectConferences" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</table>
```

with some ASP.NET methods:

```
lblNewProjectConferences.Text = UtilHTML.GetConferncesHTML(conferences, editor);
```

I am essentially building the HTML in a method and then injecting into a label which is inside of a table, the result being rows added to the table properly formatted. This is all working as expected:

[image: working properly]

But, when I do the following from javascript

```
document.getElementById("lblNewProjectConferences").innerHTML += response;
```

I get something like this:

[image: malfunctioning]

I "inspected element" from my browser and the Label is appearing before the table in HTML. This makes no sense to me.

UPDATE: The answers so far didn't help. The label code is appearing before the table code when I use innerHTML, it's not appearing first and then the table appears

[image]

Comment: Please post the entire code.

Comment: can you be more specific? all the code I have would be far too large to post in this kind of format

Answer (score 2):

I see you're using bootstrap.

You could do this also.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById("lblNewProjectConferences").innerHTML += response;
});
```

**Edited:**
Try this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblNewProjectConferences" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive table-bordered" id="gridTable">  
  <tr class="row">
    <td colspan="3" class="col-md-3">Location</td>
    <td colspan="4" class="col-md-4">Info</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="col-md-2">Date/Time</td>
    <td colspan="1" class="col-md-1">Mandatory</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="col-md-2">Edit</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And in the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#gridTable').appendTo($("#lblNewProjectConferences").html());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @TruthOf42 - I saw your update, try to change the html as I writed in answer and change the javascript also. The solution in your case its let the label outside hidden and add its html to the table.

Comment: @TruthOf42 - your real problem here is that you have positioned the label element inside the table element and the html definition doesnt recognize this because it's not part of the table element.

Answer (score 1):

You have positioned the `asp:Label` element *inside* the table before the closing `</table>` tag.  The browser does not recognize the label as part of a table, so it renders it before it renders the table.  Moving the label after the `</table>` tag should resolve the problem.

Comment: well at least that answers my question of why, but do you have any solution of how to accomplish what I'm attempting to in both asp.net AND javascript?